# Can an sklearn linear regression pipeline put a max ceiling on the output variable?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

My scikit learn pipeline is linear regression, but my problem domain should never allow the output to be above a certain value, so I want to cap the output. I know I could first run my model and then do a `y = np.where(y > MAX_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, y)` but I may have several more steps of custom logic like that, so I want to encapsulate that into the pipeline. Can sklearn do that?

I tried to write my own custom estimator like below this gives the error `All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough'` so the pipeline doesn't seem to allow putting a step after the `LinearRegression` step. Is there a way to do this?

````
import sklearn.base

class ClipOutputToMaxValue(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator, sklearn.base.RegressorMixin):
    '''custom step to put a ceiling on the output 'y' value```
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.max_y = y.max()
        return self

    def predict(self, X, y):
        y = np.where(y > self.max_y, self.max_y, y)
        return y

model =  sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline(
        [('scaler', sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
         ('model', sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()),
         ('clipper', ClipOutputToMaxValue()) #THIS IS WHAT I WANT BUT
         #SKLEARN DOESN'T ALLOW ME TO DO THIS
        ])

x = np.arange(10).reshape(10,-1)
y = x
model.fit(x, y)
model.predict(x)
````

But that fails with this error:
`TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False)' (type <class 'sklearn.linear_model.base.LinearRegression'>) doesn't`

Is there any other way?

Comment: I have sometimes used a "brick wall" implemented by the function evaluation returning a very large value - causing a large error - when a given condition occurred. In effect, the non-linear solver runs into a brick wall that it cannot pass. The initial parameter estimates must be within the limiting condition when using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is simply because the Pipeline must have only intermediate steps with fit and transform methods, except for the last step which must be a final model where the Pipeline calls the .fit method.

**From here:**

[https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html?highlight=pipeline#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline][Pipeline]

"Sequentially apply a list of transforms and a final estimator. Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they must implement fit and transform methods. The final estimator only needs to implement fit. The transformers in the pipeline can be cached using memory argument."

So, in your case you are applying a LinearRegression, that does not implements a transform method()